# Clicking Form Button using JavaScript inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this form inside **test.html** file

```
<form name="myForm1" id="myForm1" action="" method="post" onsubmit="">
    <input type="submit" value="YES" class="buttonclass"> 
</form>
```

I load it using another file called **iframe.html**

```
<iframe id="iframeID" src= "test.html"></iframe>
```

Now how can I automate the click of the submit button in the iframe using JavaScript ?

Comment: Have you tried or researched anything?

Comment: I tried but because this one doesn't have name=myButton, I cannot understand how to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('#iframeID').contentWindow
  .document.querySelector('#myForm1').submit();
```

Comment: :) if this works, I like it better than my solution.    I haven't tried to do this in a long while.

Comment: @Pavlo, is there no need to use $( document ).ready kind of approach in case the page/url inside the iframe is going to take time to load ?

Comment: I used it like this but it didn't work
`<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        document.querySelector('#iframeID').contentWindow.document.querySelector('#myForm1').submit();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframeID" src="http://localhost:8080/test.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>`


**test.html**
`<form name="myForm1" id="myForm1" action="www.google.com" method="GET" onsubmit="">
    <input type="submit" value="YES" class="buttonclass"> 
</form>`

Answer (score -1):

From an old project....

Put this in your iframe code (test.html):

```
function getElement(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

then access the element via

```
var el = document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow.getElement(id);
```

You should be able to act on that element from there.